# Chart Js Display 2 lines with same labels, not all labels have data point

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I am working in react with chart js to display data from a rest call. The data is coming in the way I want it to, but when putting it into chart js, I get 1 line that looks good, but the other goes back and forth zig zagging lines across the chart. The labels are also not displaying in the correct order. They need to be in time order. I have left my previous attempt commented out. How can I get the labels displaying in correct order and have the 2 lines display the data points to their corresponding labels?

Screenshot of chart:
[image: chart]

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react"

import {
Chart as ChartJS,
CategoryScale,
LinearScale,
PointElement,
LineElement,
Tooltip,
Legend,
TimeScale
} from 'chart.js';

import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import 'chartjs-adapter-date-fns';



export const PlayerImprovementChart = (props) => {

const [labels, setLabels] = useState([]);
const [redScores] = useState([]);
const [whiteScores] = useState([]);

const [data] = useState({
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Red Pad',
            data: redScores,
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
        },
        {
            label: 'White Pad',
            data: whiteScores,
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .5)',
        },
    ],
})

ChartJS.register(
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Tooltip,
    Legend,
    TimeScale
);

const options = {
    animation: false,
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
        legend: {
            position: 'top',
            labels: {
                color: 'white'
            },
        },
    },
    scales: {
        y: {
            ticks: { color: 'white' },
        },
        x: {
            ticks: { color: 'white' },
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Date',
            },
            // type: 'time',
            // time: {
            //     parser: 'yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss.SSS+SS:SS',
            //     unit: 'day',
            //     displayFormats: {
            //         day: 'MM-dd-yyyy'
            //     }
            // }
        },
    },
    parsing: {
        xAxisKey: 'date',
        yAxisKey: 'score'
    }
};

function clearArray(array) {
    if(array != null) {
        if(typeof array === Object) {
            array = null;
        } else {
            while (array.length > 0) {
                array.pop();
            }
        }
    }
}

//set the chart dates 
useMemo(() => {
    //clear arrays on reload
    clearArray(redScores);
    clearArray(whiteScores);


    if (props.redScores != null) {
        if (Object.keys(props.redScores).length > 0) {
            Object.keys(props.redScores).forEach(function (date) {
                if (props.redScores[date] !== 999 && props.redScores[date] !== 0) {
                    let score = props.redScores[date];
                    redScores.push({ date, score });
                }
            });
        }
    }

    if (props.whiteScores != null) {
        if (Object.keys(props.whiteScores).length > 0) {
            Object.keys(props.whiteScores).forEach(function (date) {
                if (props.whiteScores[date] !== 999 && props.whiteScores[date] !== 0) {
                    let score = props.whiteScores[date];
                    whiteScores.push({ date, score });
                }
            });
        }
    }

}, [props.dates, props.dateTo, props.dateFrom, props.redScores, props.whiteScores, labels, redScores, whiteScores]);

return (
    <div className="container">
        <Line options={options} data={data} />
    </div>
)
};

export default PlayerImprovementChart;
```

**Edit:**
Red Scores:

[image]

White scores:

[image: whiteScores:]

Comment: It seems the whiteScores data are not sorted. You could sort them before setting as data. Can you share the data you get from REST call?

Comment: Updated post to include the data

Comment: Also of note, if I remove either dataset, the remaining set appears correct. It seems to only be the second data set that is displaying correctly

Comment: I think you should use time axis instead of a category one.

Comment: Looking into this further, it is likely something with react, I tried passing the props for the date directly to the chart as labels and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You're not specifying labels. The red line's labels are at the bottom, and then the white line either used its own labels or jumped back to red to ee-use red's labels.

Where you're setting `data`, provide a `labels` property with a sorted unique array of dates from both white and red.